# iOS Application Loader: ERROR ITMS-90705: "Launch storyboard not found..."

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, ipa, application-loader

Developed iOS application using `Xamarin.Forms`. And trying to upload `ipa` file to **app store**. But on **Application Loader** I get this error:

> ERROR ITMS-90705: "Launch storyboard not found. Make sure you specify
>   the launch storyboard filename without a filename extension for the
>   key UILaunchStoryboardName in the Info.plist."

**NOTE:** I searched for solution but found nothing with this specific error. I have already

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen.storyboard</string>
```

key in info.plist file

Comment: pls try <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string> LaunchScreen </string>

Comment: remove .storyboard from string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error specifies that you have to provide the storyboard file without the extension. Try to remove the .storyboard from the key and try again.

Also, I presume the file does exist?

Comment: For who didn't understand answer, look at the first comment of @V12 below question.

Comment: @Joncom "V12" changed nickname to "MAhipal Singh", first comment under the question

Answer (score 4):

This error occur after iPad multitasking enabling by iOS11. you may remove UILaunchStoryboardName property item from Info.plist - Source tab. so that this setting will be ignored as iOS10.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, since my last upload (which worked), I added a scene to my only stoyboard, 'Main.storyboard'.  The property in Info.plist that shows in XCode as 'Launch Screen interface file base name' (and is actually the 'UILaunchStoryboardName' property if you select Editor->Show Raw Keys & Values) was 'LaunchScreen'.  I did not change that.  And there never has been a 'LaunchScreen'.

Deleting it as some folks suggested seriously damaged  my layouts.  Suddenly a lot of things were mis-positioned and I could not get the right screen dimensions.

So I simply changed the property to 'Main', and everything worked!

Note that I was also getting ITS-90706, which this also cleared up.

This was under XCode 10.1 (10B61) (Which was also new since my last upload)